# ImportError: cannot import name 'expected_conditions' from 'selenium.webdriver.support.ui'

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to run a web scraper using selenium and python. I have imported the necessary modules and set the path to the ChromeDriver executable, but I keep getting the following error when I try to run the script: "ImportError: cannot import name 'expected_conditions' from 'selenium.webdriver.support.ui'".

I have already tried uninstalling and reinstalling the selenium module, but the error persists. I have also checked to make sure that I am using the most up-to-date version of ChromeDriver.

I used tools like curl, wget, HTTrack,  but nothing seems to work installing pass the login page because my website has a javascript login prompt. I am open to new tools if you have suggestions.

Can anyone please help me figure out what's going wrong? I'm not very familiar with web scraping or debugging, so any advice would be greatly appreciated.

I have followed a tutorial and written the following code:

```
import os
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

# Set the path to the ChromeDriver executable
chrome_driver_path = r"C:\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe"

# Initialize a Chrome webdriver instance
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver_path)

# Navigate to the login page
driver.get("https://lms.infowerk.at/mysite")
print(driver.page_source)

# Wait for the username field to be present in the DOM
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    lambda driver: driver.find_element(By.NAME, "username")
)

# Find the login form elements and enter the login credentials
driver.find_element(By.NAME, "Username").send_keys("denis")
driver.find_element(By.NAME, "Password").send_keys("thebestpassword")

# Submit the login form
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@type='submit']").click()

# Wait for the page to load
time.sleep(5)

# Create a directory to store the page HTML files if it doesn't already exist
if not os.path.exists("D:/mysite"):
    os.makedirs("D:/mysite")

# Save the current URL for later use
current_url = driver.current_url

# Save the HTML of the current page to a file
with open("D:/mysite/index.html", "w") as f:
    f.write(driver.page_source)

# Find all of the links on the page
links = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a")

# Iterate over the links
for link in links:
    href = link.get_attribute("href")
    if href.startswith(current_url):
        driver.get(href)
        with open("D:/mysite/" + href.split("/")[-1], "w") as f:
            f.write(driver.page_source)
```

And this is the error message that I am receiving"

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'expected_conditions' from 'selenium.webdriver.support.ui'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the below import statement as well:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
```